# copy files only when they do not exist at destination

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I want to copy many files in many folders form one hard disk A to another harddisk B.

How can I copy only files from A to B and skip the copy if the files already exist at B?

Is this possible with xcopy?

Comment: XCOPY have no such option... use EXPLORER, it can skip overwriting for all duplicates.

Comment: On a per folder basis you could use `Replace /A`

Comment: @Akina: I would like to know how the Shell command is.

Comment: If so use per-file recursive iteration and copy each file separately with "ask for overwrite" option and unconditional `n<Enter>` entered into via std pipe.

Comment: use robocopy it has such options

Comment: xcopy can copy-if-src-file-is-newer by checking dates. IDK if this is the behavior you're looking for because it WILL overwrite if a file at A is newer and file at B is older.

Comment: Worth clarifying what "already exist at B". When is it deemed to be the same?  Name? Size? Checksum?  For me it has to be checksum but if performance is a real concern this might not be the "best" option.  As you have tagged Powershell, you can use Test-Path to simply see if the file exists by path and therefore name, but I would suggest you really want to consider the checksum of the file.  Of course, to get the checksum, this is going to have some performance impact over just testing the filename/path which doesn't require opening the file.  Confirming this is the first step I would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can  pipe the results of a recursive GCI of the source, test if its a Folder or File then use this object to test path to check if present in destination folder.

something like ...

```
   # Initial setup defaults
    $Start = Date # Uses this start time at the end to calculate how long the process took!
    $src = 'C:\Original Folder'
    $dest = 'D:\New Folder'

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Recurse | 

           % {
             If ($_.PSIsContainer)
              { If (Test-Path (Join-Path (Join-Path $dest $_.Parent.FullName.SubString($src.Length)) $_.BaseName)){
                    }Else{
                        $_ | Copy-Item  -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($src.length)} -Force #-Whatif
                    }
                }Else{
                    If (Test-Path (Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.SubString($src.Length))){ 
                    }Else{
                    $_ | Copy-Item  -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.Substring($src.length)} -Force #-Whatif
              }
             }
            }  -ErrorAction Continue


    $End = Date
    $TimeDiff = New-TimeSpan $Start $End
    $Difference = "{0:G}" -f $TimeDiff

Write-Host " Scan time " $Difference " [(Days) Hours Minutes Seconds]"
```

If the test path on the file is successful but you have files with same names but different timestamps then you will need to implement some kind of compare between files or check file last write times something like this

```
If ($_.LastWriteTime -gt ((Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.SubString($src.Length)).LastWriteTime)){ $_ | Copy-Item  -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.Substring($src.length) }}
```